# JavaScript: Namespace error when using xmlDoc.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to get an XPathResult object using the evalute() function on a xml document object:

```
var nodes= xmlDoc.evaluate(XMLPath,xmlDoc,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
```

even though the namespaceResolver parameter is `null` and I am using a very simple XML file without any name spaces declared, Firefox throws the following error on the line:

> NamespaceError: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a
>   way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces

Where is my error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad. The error was hiding in the actual XPath I used. Problem solved.